# Linq statement body equivalent for IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this

```
var total = 0;

someObject.SomeCollection.SelectMany(x=> x.SomeOtherCollection.ForEach(y=>{
   total = y.AnotherCollection.Sum(z=> z.Total);
});
```

Now I need to do this,

Query (is IQueryable)

```
Query.Where(x => MyTotal == (x.SomeCollection.SelectMany.. just as above and returns the Total)).
```

I realize that I can't write a query with a statement body in linq to sql.

Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: The existence of `ForEach` within a Linq expression hurts my eyes - can you explain in words what the intent of the query is?  Linq queries aren't supposed to have side-effects.

Comment: I'd actually be surprised if it compiled since `SelectMany` requires a delegate that returns an `IEnumerable` and `ForEach` is a void method.

Comment: I don't think this dose what you want? Your query returns the sum of you last element I think you are missing +=. but this can't be done with IQueryable.ForEach and Body expression don't work

Comment: Stanley it does compile and work and filip you're right I am missing the +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

)Going to answer my own question.

Equivalent of this:

```
var total = 0;

someObject.SomeCollection.SelectMany(x=> x.SomeOtherCollection.ForEach(y=>{
   total = y.AnotherCollection.Sum(z=> z.Total);
});
```

is this:

```
Query.Where(x => MyTotal == (x.SomeCollection.SelectMany(y=> y.SomeOtherCollection).SelectMany(z=> z.AnotherCollection).Sum(t=> t.Total)));
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

What I think you wanted was this

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i=>new { Items = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(j=>new { Total = j }).AsQueryable() }).AsQueryable();

var total = items.Sum(i => i.Items.Sum(j => j.Total));
```